# Remove the Share element icon from Fancybox in code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wonder if there is a way to remove the share option element from the fancybox toolbar. I set the class to display none but it just removed the icon [img toolbar in fancybox with the share icon removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOAz8.png), I want to remove the whole entire element if there is a way. Any help would be appreciated.

```
.fancybox-button--share svg path{
    display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, the problem has been solved, It worked. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unnecessary to use **css** here. To add / remove a button from the `fancybox` panel, you just need to list the buttons you need in the initialization:

```
$(selector).fancybox({
    ...
    buttons : [
        'slideShow',
        'zoom',
        'fullScreen',
        'close'
    ]
    ...
});
```